# Assigning values to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question about signing values to array. I have copied my code below(I am a newbie)
After compilation and execution of my code I can only see the last value in array. Why? It's a very basic cipher

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CipherManager {

    String message;
    int key;
    int basic = -72;
    int array[];

    public void cipher() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a text you want to cipher");
        message = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Write down a number key");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {

            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                key = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error, enter a number ");
                sc.next();
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(message.charAt(i));
            array = new int[message.length()];
            int litera = message.charAt(i) + key + basic;
            array[i] = letter;

        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Comment: That code won't compile (`letter` is not declared anywhere). If it *did* compile, it wouldn't have the behavior you describe (it would blow up with a `NullPointerException` on the `array[i]=letter;` line, as you've never initialized `array`).

Comment: It is generally helpful if you make some effort to actually follow formatting conventions i.e. indentation when posting code as it makes your question very hard to understand.  Also your code as written does not make sense as you use a variable `tablica` which you never officially define.  As for your actual problem you are reassigning the array to a new array in every iteration of your for loop which wipes out the previous values hence why the final array only has the last letter set

Comment: Well you're right, I was translating my variables to english in hurry, and i unfortunately skipped few of them. Gotta be more carefull in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your current code is (your `array` array is never initialized, and since you don't get a `NullPointerException`, you are probably not using it) :

```
         for (int i = 0; i < wiadomosc.length(); i++) {
           System.out.print(message.charAt(i));
           tablica=new int[message.length()];     
           int litera = message.charAt(i)+key + basic;
           tablica[i]=letter;
         }
```

It should be:

```
         tablica=new int[message.length()];     
         for (int i = 0; i < wiadomosc.length(); i++) {
           System.out.print(message.charAt(i));
           int litera = message.charAt(i)+key + basic;
           tablica[i]=letter;
         }
```

The `tablica` array should only be initialized once, before the loop. Initializing it inside the loop in each iteration makes the values previously assigned (to previous arrays) inaccessible.

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything is clear for me:) That was a trivial mistake